# Find all functions that satisfy $f(\frac{x+4}{1-x}) + f(x) = x$

Tags: functional-equations

I found the following task in a book and I would be interested if someone has an idea to solve it:

Find all the functions $f$ that satisfy $f(\frac{x+4}{1-x}) + f(x) = x$.

My ideas:

Assuming that $f$ is a power series or making a substitution.

I tried several approaches, but without success.

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't any other information?  For example, I assume this is a real-valued function

Comment: Oh, I' m sorry. The only other Information is that the functions are real-valued and defined for $x \neq \pm 1$.

Comment: The function*s* and why wouldn't it (they) be defined for $x=-1$? Are you sure there's not some details you've left out?

Comment: @Henrik I think it's not defined for $x=-1$ so future manipulations can be made (see my partial answer)

Comment: Can you give the source of this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I loaned the book from a library and I have it returned already.

Answer (score 15):

The equation reads $$\tag1f(g(x))+f(x)=x$$
where $g(z)=\frac{z+4}{-z+1}$ is a Möbius transformation (a nice bijection of $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself) with fix points $\pm2i$.
The Möbius transform $h(z)=\frac{z-2i}{z+2i}$ maps $2i\mapsto 0$ and $-2i\mapsto \infty$ and has an inverse transform $k(z)=\frac{2iz+2i}{-z+1}$. Note that
$$G(z):=h(g(k(z))) = \underbrace{\frac{-3+4i}{5}}_{=:\alpha}\cdot z$$
is just a rotation by an *irrational* (see below) angle.
Now
$$ f(k(G(z)))+f(h^{-1}(z))=k(z)$$
so that $F(z):=f(k(z))$ (which leads to $f(z)=F(h(z))$) obeys the functional equation
$$\tag2F(\alpha z)+F(z)=k(z).$$
If we do not postulate continuity, we only find $F(0)=\frac12k(0)=i$ and $F(\infty)=\frac12k(\infty)=-i$, and beyond that we can pick an arbitrary value per equivalence class of $\Bbb C^\times$ modulo multiplication with $\alpha$.

From $F(1)+F(\alpha)=k(1)=\infty$, we see that at least one of $F(1)$, $F(\alpha)$ must be infinite. 
As the set $\{\alpha^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is dense in $S^1$, we conclude that $F(z)=\infty$ for a set that is dense in $S^1$.
If $F$ is continuous (as a map of $\Bbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ to itself), this implies $F(z)=\infty$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$. This means that $f(z)=\infty$ for all $z\in\Bbb R$, so we better consider $F$ only inside or outside the unit circle, $f$ only on the upper or lower half plane.

One may argue that the instances of $(1)$ that involve infinity, i.e., the cases $x=1$ and $x=\infty$, do not apply; this means we split this one orbit into two half-orbits. However, this changes the situation only when we allow non-continuous $f$ in the first place.

If we demand $F$ to be smooth, then we find $\alpha F'(\alpha z)+F'(z)=k'(z)=\frac{4i}{(z-1)^2}$, 
in particular $F'(0)=\frac{4i}{1+\alpha}$.
Next,
$\alpha^2 F''(\alpha z)+F''(z)=-8i(z-1)^{-3}$ and more generally
$$ \alpha^nF^{(n)}(\alpha z)+F^{(n)}(z)=4in!(1-z)^{-n}$$
and in particular
$$ F^ {(n)}(0)=\frac{4in!}{1+\alpha^n}$$
fo $n>0$.
Therefore, we make an analytic "attempt"
$$ F(z)=i+4i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{1+\alpha^n}.$$
The convergence seems to be non-trivial, though, as $\alpha^n+1$ becomes arbitrarily small. (As mentioned in the comments, this is related to the irrationality measure of $\alpha$, so probably ew are now way beyond the level where the original question occured - if we have not left that level a lot earlier).

*Remark:* That $\alpha$ is an irrational rotation ultimately follows from the number-theoretical fact that $1+2i$ and $1-2i$ are non-associate primes in the ring $\Bbb Z[i]$

---

Based on the niveau and context of the problem source, it may be more appropriate to show the following simpler

**Claim.** There is no *continuous* function  $f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$  such that $(1)$ holds for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$.

*Proof.* 
Assume that $f$ is continuous. Then in particular, $f$ is bounded by some $M$ on the interval $(-3,6)$. Then $f$ is bounded by $M+6$ on $\{\,g(x)\mid -2<x<4,x\ne1\,\}$, i.e., on both  $(\tfrac 74,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-2)$. Hence $f$ is bounded by $M+6$, which gives a contradiction with $(1)$ for $x$ with $|x|>2(M+6)$. $\square$

Comment: Just a small correction; we have $F(0) = k(0)/2 = i$ not $2i$ so your formula for $F(z)$ has the wrong constant term.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. This is a great answer, but I think there also exists a simpler solution without Möbius transformation as the book in which I found this Task is about a beginners lecture in calculus.

Comment: Convergence of the $F$-series seems to be related to the irrationality measure of $\zeta = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\arctan(3/4)}{\pi}$ ($\alpha = e^{i\pi \zeta}$). If $\zeta$ has a finite irrationality measure (which it’s almost surely has) then the series should converge for $|z| < 1$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks

Comment: @Peter123 Well, at a beginner's level it might be sufficient to show: "There does not exist a continuous function $f\colon D\to\Bbb R$ where domain $D\subseteq \Bbb R$ with $\Bbb R\setminus D$ nowhere dense and $f(\tfrac {x+4}{1-x})+f(x)0x$ holds for all $x\ne 1$ with $x,\frac{x+4}{1-x}\in D$" (just to turn the task into an explicit statement). This might be doable without using too much knowledge about Möbius transforms

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Thank you very much. Is there a reason why the author assumed that the functions are not defined for $x = -1$? You just didn' t need that. 

Do you know if there are non continuous functions that satisfy the condition?

Comment: @Peter123 Huh? Where did the author assume that $f$ is not defined at $x=-1$? I see no information whatsoever about the domain of $f$ in the probelm statement ...

Comment: @Peter123 Even if we search only for continuous $f\colon\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,1\}\to\Bbb R$, there is no such function: From $g(-1)=\frac32$, we see that $\lim_{x\to-1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-1}(x-f(g(x))=-1-f(\tfrac32)$.  Likewise, we have $g(-\tfrac32)=1$ and so $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -\frac32}f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to-\frac32}(x-f(x))=-\frac32-f(-\tfrac32)$. As there is no real number with $g(x)=-1$ and also $g(1)$ is not defined, we can just as well extend $f$ by defining $f(-1)=-1-f(\tfrac32)$ and $f(1)=-\frac32-f(-\tfrac32)$, and it will still be continuous and obeying the functional equation.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Have a look at the discussion in the comments beneath the question.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Thank you. Does your argumentation even hold if we modify the condition to $f(\frac{x+4}{1 - \frac{1}{3}x}) + f(x) = x$?

Comment: @Peter123 Ah, now I see. Seriously, information that changes the problem statement that much *ought* to be edited into the question itself ...

Comment: @Peter123 The argument should be the same for *any* Möbius transform in place of $g$, as long as it maps the extended reals to themselves (i.e., has all coefficients real) and is conjugate to an irrational rotation. That should include $\frac{x+4}{1-\frac13x}$. Of course, here $3$ takes the role of $1$ and $-3$ the role of $-1$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: You just proved that there is no continuous function $f$ that satisfies the condition, but are there functions $f$ which are not continous that satisfy the condition, too?

Answer (score 3):

This was the closest I got.  Feel free to point out any mistakes.

We have $$f\left(\frac{x+4}{1-x}\right)+f(x)=x$$

The inside of the first one can be simplified to $\frac{5}{1-x}-1$, so the expression becomes $$f\left(\frac{5}{1-x}-1\right)+f(x)=x\tag{1}$$

Making the transformation $\frac{5}{1-x}-1\rightarrow x$ yields $$f(x)+f\left(1-\frac{5}{x+1}\right)=1-\frac{5}{x+1}\tag{2}$$

Now making the substitution $x\rightarrow -x$ in $(1)$ gives us $$f\left(\frac{5}{1+x}-1\right)+f(-x)=-x$$

Adding this to $(2)$ gives us $$\left[f\left(1-\frac{5}{x+1}\right)+f\left(\frac{5}{1+x}-1\right)\right]+\left[f(x)+f(-x)\right]=1-\frac{5}{x+1}-x\implies \\$$

$$\boxed{\left[f(y)+f(-y)\right]+\left[f(x)+f(-x)\right]=y-x}$$

subject to $y=1-\frac{5}{x+1}$

This looked really good because the lefthand side is the sum of two even functions, while the righthand side is a difference of two odd functions.  However, this isn't necessarily a contradiction, since there are two variables.  Either way, I think this fully describes the symmetry of the function.  I hope this helps someone come to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $T(x+1)=\dfrac{T(x)+4}{1-T(x)}$ ,

Let $T(x)=U(x)+1$ ,

Then $U(x+1)+1=\dfrac{U(x)+5}{-U(x)}$

$U(x+1)+1=-1-\dfrac{5}{U(x)}$

$U(x+1)=-2-\dfrac{5}{U(x)}$

Let $U(x)=\dfrac{V(x+1)}{V(x)}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{V(x+2)}{V(x+1)}=-2-\dfrac{5V(x)}{V(x+1)}$

$\dfrac{V(x+2)}{V(x+1)}=-\dfrac{2V(x+1)+5V(x)}{V(x+1)}$

$V(x+2)+2V(x+1)+5V(x)=0$

$V(x)=\theta_1(x)(-1+2i)^x+\theta_2(x)(-1-2i)^x$ , where $\theta_1(x)$ and $\theta_2(x)$ are arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$V(x)=\theta_1(x)e^{x\ln(-1+2i)}+\theta_2(x)e^{x\ln(-1-2i)}$ , where $\theta_1(x)$ and $\theta_2(x)$ are arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$V(x)=\theta_1(x)e^{\frac{x\ln5}{2}+(\pi-\tan^{-1}2)ix}+\theta_2(x)e^{\frac{x\ln5}{2}-(\pi-\tan^{-1}2)ix}$ , where $\theta_1(x)$ and $\theta_2(x)$ are arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$V(x)=\Theta_1(x)5^\frac{x}{2}\sin((\tan^{-1}2)x)+\Theta_2(x)5^\frac{x}{2}\cos((\tan^{-1}2)x)$ , where $\Theta_1(x)$ and $\Theta_2(x)$ are arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$\therefore T(x)=\dfrac{\Theta_1(x+1)5^\frac{x+1}{2}\sin((\tan^{-1}2)(x+1))+\Theta_2(x+1)5^\frac{x+1}{2}\cos((\tan^{-1}2)(x+1))}{\Theta_1(x)5^\frac{x}{2}\sin((\tan^{-1}2)x)+\Theta_2(x)5^\frac{x}{2}\cos((\tan^{-1}2)x)}+1$ , where $\Theta_1(x)$ and $\Theta_2(x)$ are arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$T(x)=\dfrac{\Theta(x)\sqrt5\sin((\tan^{-1}2)(x+1))+\sqrt5\cos((\tan^{-1}2)(x+1))}{\Theta(x)\sin((\tan^{-1}2)x)+\cos((\tan^{-1}2)x)}+1$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Hence $f(2-2\tan((\tan^{-1}2)(x+1)))+f(2-2\tan((\tan^{-1}2)x))=2-2\tan((\tan^{-1}2)x)$